# Remove Authorize rule for specific API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorize, system.web.http

I have a WEB Api controller, that has the [Authorize] tag at the top of the controller - which means all API in this class will have this rule applied. Like this:

```
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/v1/route")]
        public class ItemController : ApiController
    {
/// Etc...
```

My issue is that for a specific call within this class, I do not want this Auth rule to apply. I am sure I have seen a way of doing this before, but for all my googling I cannot find it. I think it is something like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("singleCall")]
        [NOTAUTH]//whatever should go in here
        public void Log()
        {
```

Any ideas???

Comment: You mean [AllowAnonymous] ?

Comment: @Neil yes that is the one - you should ad it is an answer

Comment: if you leave api without `[Authorize]` then such api treated as `[AllowAnonymous]` no need to add such attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `[AllowAnonymous]`.

[This page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute/) has some examples.

Answer (score 2):

You Can use `[AllowAnonymous]` Attribute. 
Please refer to this article in order to know how to use them in conjunction with `[Authorize]` attribute.
[ASP.NET MVC AllowAnonymous Attribute and Authorize Attribute](https://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-allowanonymous-attribute-and-authorize-attribute)